# How do I check if a List of Maps does *not* contain a specific key in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I check if a List of Maps `List<Map<String, List<CustomObject>>> listOfMaps` does *not* contain a specific key?

I am looping through `listOfMaps` and checking if a map contains a specific key.

If so I write over the values (code below):

```
listOfMaps.forEach((map) {
      if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        // write over values...
      }
    });
```

However if the listOfMaps does not contain the key I want to add the new map to the list:

```
listOfMaps.add(
        {key: [
      // Custom Objects
    ]}
    );
```

How do I check if `listOfMaps` does *not* contain a specific key?

*Edit:

```
listOfMaps = [
{'map1': [listOfCustomObjects]},
{'map2': [listOfCustomObjects]},
{'map3': [listOfCustomObjects]},
]
```

I am now dealing with new data:
`{'map4': [listOfCustomObjects]}`

if listOfMaps doesn't contain key 'map4' I want to add a map, if listOfMaps does contain 'map4' already I want to write over the values.

Also of note, I know that each map in listOfMaps will contain *only 1* key.

Comment: the way I'm looping through each map in the list there should be lots of maps that don't contain that key...??

Comment: As I said in my answer, this should not be a list of maps that each have a single key, but rather a map with many keys and values for each key.

Comment: Right.  However for various reasons related to how I've structured my database I know that each map will only ever have 1 key and then values of a list of custom objects with many keys and values ... if that makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways:

Use `Iterable.any(...)`.

```
if (listOfMaps.any((m) => m.containsKey(key))) {
  // Do something
} else {
  // Add new map to listOfMaps
}
```

Use a flag:

```
bool found = false;
listOfMaps.forEach((map) {
  if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    found = true;
    // write over values...
  }
});
if (!found) {
  listOfMaps.add(
    {key: [
      // Custom Objects
    ]}
  );
}
```

Comment: This works.  ```Iterable.any(...)``` was a much cleaner way of doing things than what I previously had.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works but seems a little awkward... If anybody has a simpler way of doing it let me know...

```
  checkIfListOfMapsContainsKey({
    required String key,
    required List<Map<String, List<CustomObject>>> listOfMaps,
  }) {
    bool hasKey = false;
    listOfMaps.forEach((map) {
      if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        hasKey = true;
      }
    });
    return hasKey;
  }
```

then:

```
bool hasKey = checkIfListOfMapsContainsKey(
          key: key,
          listOfMaps: listOfMaps,
        );
        if (hasKey == false) {
          listOfMaps.add({'map4': [listOfObjects]});
          
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough.

```
listOfMaps.update('map4', (old) => (old with new), ifAbsent: () => new);
```

EDIT: ooops. That's not the problem to be solved.  I'll just leave this here because people forget this works for some problems. {sigh}

I'd also suggest that the ordering of the maps is likely insignificant, so this should really just be a map with keys, not a list of maps with a single key, and then my solution is applicable.

Comment: I'm getting  The method 'update' isn't defined for the type 'List'.

Comment: Uh, you made a comment on an unrelated *answer* I made to get me to look at a *different* question?  Please... there are MANY people who can answer things here.  Don't single me out.  I'm just a volunteer, not a help desk!